# Where do I get Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard?

Tags: xcode, osx-snow-leopard, 32-bit

I went to the downloads section on the [Apple Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) but I can only see `Xcode 4.2 for Lion`. I need to get the version that is for Snow Leopard and will run on 32-bit. Can anyone point me to the correct place?

The last available Xcode version for Snow Leopard on dev site is Xcode 3.2.6.

Comment: Side note - keep in mind that you need at least Xcode 4.5 (support for iOS 6.0) to build apps you wish to submit to the App Store. This means you need at least Lion or Mountain Lion.

Comment: Will iOS SDK 5.1 not work?

Comment: As of May 1st, Apple requires that all apps submitted to the store must fully support the 4" screens of the iPhone 5 and 5th gen iPod touch. Support for this was added in Xcode 4.5. I suppose you can still find a way to add the required launch images with earlier versions of Xcode. Apple likes to keep moving forward. Modern iOS app development is only officially supported with newer versions of Xcode on Lion or Mountain Lion. Anything earlier becomes a hack and you are on your on for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3537806?start=30&tstart=0

You must be a registered developer with a paid account in order to download Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard from the apple downloads section. 
There is a screen shot there showing the download is available from apple if you meet these conditions.

Comment: Build a hackintosh if you don't want to shell out for a new apple. I'm running one here on a Q6600 quad core processor. You could probably pick up something later gen core 2 or sandybridge i5 for really cheap.